# TypeError: Iniciar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data' and failed append

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to append the input numbers to my array data everytime I click the button "agregar", however it seems like it only appends the value i just inserted and completely forgets about the previous append. I don't get any error messaged with that one. Also, when I click  "iniciar" it should draw ovals with the values in data but I get the error

> TypeError: Iniciar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from array import *
import random 

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Bubble Sort')
tk.maxsize(900, 600)
tk.config(bg = 'black')

#Variables
algoritmo = StringVar()

#comandos 

def dibujar(data):
    c.delete("all") 
    cHeight = 380
    cWidth = 600 

    #para escalar 
    algoWidth = cWidth /  (len(data) + 1)
    algoHeight = cWidth /  (len(data) + 1)
    offset = 20
    spacing = 10

    tamData = [i / max(data) for i in data]

    for i, height in enumerate(tamData):
        #top left
        x0 = i * algoWidth + offset + spacing
        y0 = cHeight - height * 50

        #botom right
        x1 = (i+1) * algoWidth + offset
        y1 = cHeight 

        c.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill = 'red')
        c.create_text(x0+2,y0, anchor = SW, text=str(data[i]))

def Iniciar(data):
    print("Se selecciono: " + algoritmo.get())
 
    dibujar(a)

def agregar():
    data = array('i', [1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
    input =  int(inputVal.get())
    data.append((input))

    print("valor input:")
    print(input)
    print(str(data))


def limpiar():
    c.delete("all") 
    

#Frame
box = Frame(tk, width = 600, height = 200, bg = 'black' )
box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=10, pady=5)
c = Canvas(tk, width = 600, height = 380,  bg = 'grey')
c.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx=10, pady=5)

#UI
#Row-0
label = Label(box, text='Lista Algoritmos: ', font = ("Arial",15), borderwidth=1, bg = "black" , fg = 'white')
label.grid(row=0,column=0,  padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)

menu = ttk.Combobox(box, textvariable = algoritmo, values=['BUBBLE SORT', 'MERGE SORT', 'HASH TABLES', 'ARBOL AVL', 'ARBOLES ROJO Y NEGRO'])
menu.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
menu.current(0)

botonStart = Button(box, text = 'Iniciar', command = Iniciar, bg = 'lime green')
botonStart.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

#Row-1 
label = Label(box, text='Insertar valor: ', font = ("Arial",15), borderwidth=1, bg = "black" , fg = 'white')
label.grid(row=1,column=0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)
inputVal = Entry(box)
inputVal.grid(row=1,column=1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)

botonAdd = Button(box, text = 'Agregar', command = agregar, bg = 'lime green')
botonAdd.grid(row = 1, column = 2,  padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)

botonClear = Button(box, text = 'Limpiar', command = limpiar, bg = 'lime green')
botonClear.grid(row = 1, column = 3,  padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)


tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: First change `def Iniciar(data):` to `def Iniciar():`.  Second move `data = array(...)` inside `agregar()` out of `agregar()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `Iniciar` here:

```
def Iniciar(data):
    print("Se selecciono: " + algoritmo.get())
 
    dibujar(a)
```

But when you call it below you aren't passing a `data` argument to it

```
botonStart = Button(box, text = 'Iniciar', command = Iniciar, bg = 'lime green')
```

Comment: ooooooooooooh, I see, thank you! Any idea on how to fix the append issue?

Comment: Try changing `data.append((input))` to `data = data.append((input))`

Comment: I've tried doing that and for whatever reason it gives me the error message saying that I need to add a numerical value

Comment: not sure on that piece then, sorry. Good luck